# HTTPS is not working in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, tomcat7

I have a server running great on http.
I've got a certificate from GD and installed it according to the instructions.

I have the certificates located at: ~/crt (full path /home/ubuntu/crt)

The configuration in server.xml is:

`<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="443"/>`

and for the SSL:

`<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" alias="tomcat"
               keystoreFile="/home/ubuntu/crt/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="THE ACTUAL PASSWORD" 
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />`

I've added the AUTHBIND=yes to /etc/defaults/tomcat7 as well as touch both 80 and 443

When I perform: `netstat -anp | grep 443`

I get that line:

```
netstat -anp | grep 443
```

Now, calling to the server via http works great but via https.. nothing... getting "this webpage not available" error in Chrome

---------------- EDIT -------------------------
At the end I've simply regenerated the SSL and reinstall it and now its working.. really dont know what I did wrong - but its working fine now!

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the catalina.log when you start up?

Comment: Nope.. at the end I've simply regenerated the SSL and reinstall it and now its working.. really dont know what I did wrong - but its working fine now!

Comment: What do you mean "regenerated the SSL"?  You ran `keytool` again?

Comment: Yes - run it again the same way as before and worked..

Comment: Ever figure this out? Is there a log file somewhere? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Never did.. Once I've ran the keytool again and install it again it worked..